# jQuery textarea word count on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been looking around for a function that counts the number of words in a textarea when I click the form submit button.

I am trying to display a message to the user that if they click submit and have only entered 50 or less words. This will be a confirm message basically saying "You have entered less than 50 words, are you sure you would like to continue?"...or something.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<form id="confirmForm">
    <textarea id="moreThan50"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>​
```

JS:

```
$('#confirmForm').submit(function(ev){
    var wordCount = $('#moreThan50').val().split(/\s/g).length;

    if (wordCount < 50) {
        if (!confirm('Less than 50 words, are you sure you want to submit?')) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});​
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S26CF/)

Comment: Form controls must have a name to be successful, this form will not submit any data.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `split` method using a space as a splitter, and then you take the length of the array.

```
var wordCount = $('textarea').val().split(' ').length
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method, you can use regex and count 'words' using `\b`:

```
var words = $('#textareaid').val().match(/\b(\w+)\b)/g).length;
```

**Ninja-Edit** Oops, should have been `.val` not `.text`

Answer (score 1):

You can split at word boundaries using regular expressions..

```
$('form').submit(function(){
   var words = $('textarea', this).val().split(/\b\W/);
   if (words.length < 50){
     // propmpt here.. and allow or cancel the submit..
   }
});
```